# Is it possible to add a button to a scroll view?

Tags: android, xml, layout, button, scrollviewer

I have a simple `ScrollView` in a `layout` that displays an `About Box` in a dialog format.  So it just pops up on the phone screen in a dialog.  The only way for the user to close the box is to click the back button (it is an intent).

Do I have a way of adding a close `button` to the box or could I have the user hit the box on the screen with their finger and close it?

Here is my `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/about_box"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/about_text" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Btw... just got your email... hope you fixed everything already XD

Comment: The views are working great actually!  Thank you!  Since it is multiple linear layouts, do I have the option of being able to hit the back button in them to go back to the previous screen?  Or is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > The only way for the user to close the box is to click the back button

That's what any Android user would want to do. Anyway, if you want to provide the "close with button" functionality just keep in mind this: ScrollView cannot contain more than one item, so you will have to wrap both `TextView` and Button inside a `LinearLayout` or something.

But, my suggestion is that you should build an `AlertDialog`, which can be automatically configured with an "OK" button which will close the dialog.

Comment: Do I put an alert dialog inside the scroll view in the xml file?

Comment: Yes... just use the `AlertDialog.Builder` class, and invoke its `setView` method. It receives a `View` that you have inflate before.

Comment: Oh I know what you mean, I created an alert dialog with a eula in a sample program I made a while back...so basically, with scrollview, I have no way of closing the about box unless the back button is clicked?  Otherwise, I would have to use a alert box?